# Trouble with navbar and scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help, my navbar is transparent background, so when I do scroll > 540px the navbar turns black, but when the scrolling is > 540px and updated the page the navbar becomes transparent until I make a minimum scroll, how can I fix the problem?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 540) {
        $('.sec').addClass('navbar-index-scroll animated fadeInDown').removeClass('fadeOutUp');
    } else {
        $('.sec').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp');
    }
});
```

Comment: but the problem is when refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate the website, say using refresh or history (Back/Forward) buttons, the old scroll state *can* be remembered by the browser.

To compensate for the page being already scrolled you can:

```
// 1. Create a function to handle the navbar states/styles

function navbarScrollposStyles() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 540) {
        $('.sec').addClass('navbar-index-scroll animated fadeInDown').removeClass('fadeOutUp');
    } else {
        $('.sec').removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp');
    }
}

$(navbarScrollposStyles);                           // 2. Do on DOM ready and 
$(window).on('load scroll', navbarScrollposStyles); // 3. on window.onload and onscroll
```

P.S: in your specific code I cannot make sense of the classes `navbar-index-scroll animated` not being handled properly in the `else` block, …but that's another pair of shoes.

Additionally it's really expensive to query the document on every scroll *"tick"* (event) for some `.sec` elements. You should **cache your selectors** into a variable like `var $sec = $(".sec");` -
also you could prevent such event from being fired too much times and degrade performance - by using some **[Throttle function](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/)**.